# Puppeteer: browser.newPage is not a function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

here is my code to connect to an open browser

```
pptr = require('puppeteer-core');
pptr.launch({headless: false,
executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default'})
.then(async browser => {
page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
})
```

But node.js always complains
"browser.newPage is not a function"

Please help. Thanks

Comment: browser is undefined. where do you save it?

Comment: Code looks good to me. Are you sure this is a [mcve]? As an aside, I strongly recommend using `const` in front of all variables, otherwise you're polluting the global scope.

Comment: @chovy Well, I'm just new to Node.js. I declared the browser variable and the error disapeared. But it throwed another error:
Invalid REPL keyword

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Typescript project. Someone on Guilded helped me resolve this with a pretty simple fix. Basically both the `puppeteer.launch({});` and `browser.newPage();` return a promise, so you will need to await them both. And the Launch should be in an async function I believe. Though with your code I'm not quite sure if this does it for ya. Here is a cut out of my own code.

```
  async execute(message: Message, args: any) {
    // Check if search is a ship
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://starcitizen.tools/' + qry);
}
```